# Azure Functions and F# Json Type Provider

Tags: azure-functions, f#-data

I am using the F# Type Provider for the first time in Azure Functions.  Here is the run.fsx file:

```
#r "FSharp.Data"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

open System
open FSharp.Data
open Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table

type Tweet = JsonProvider<"sample.json">

let Run (queueItem: string, tweets: ICollector<Tweet>) =  
    ()
```

Here is the project.json file:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "dependencies": {
        "FSharp.Data": "2.3.2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

sample.json is located in the same folder as the other files

When I run it, I am getting this:

```
> 2017-02-06T13:40:22.946
> D:\home\site\wwwroot\TweeterDataCleaner\run.fsx(9,14): error FS3033:
> The type provider 'ProviderImplementation.JsonProvider' reported an
> error: Cannot read sample JSON from 'sample.json': Could not find file
> 'D:\Windows\system32\sample.json'
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround when I had similar issue - using `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` value (constant? symbol? I'm not sure what it is exactly):

```
[<Literal>]
let sample = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + "/sample.json"
type Tweet = JsonProvider<sample>
```

I would love to learn if there is a better way to specify this.

Comment: That worked - thanks.  I asked Don Syme what __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ is, he said "Errr. a hack?"

Comment: Ideally, Azure Functions would set the working directory for a function execution to that function. At present, it does not. SOURCE_DIRECTORY looks like a macro which resolves to the directory of the F# source file, something like: $env:HOME + '/site/wwwroot/<functionname>/<scriptfile>'. It's definitely the easiest way to do this at present, as I believe changing the function working directory could modify the working directory for other .net functions as well.

Comment: The pattern above (using the HOME environment variable + path) is the recommended approach for now. We do plan to expose this in a more convenient way so you don't have to jump through hoops.